# Depth First Search Implementation - understanding swift code

Tags: swift, data-structures

I was going thru few tutorials for Tree DS and I found this code which is really confusing to understand. Please explain

```
public func forEachDepthFirst(visit: (TreeNode) -> Void) {
        visit(self) // 1

        children.forEach { // 2
            $0.forEachDepthFirst(visit: visit)
        }
    }
}
```

Why do we have visit(self) here?

I see explanation here https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/help-understanding-the-recursion-for-depth-first-traversal/56552/2 but its still not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any recusive method has

1- base case : which ends the run and here it's

```
children.forEach // when children property is empty meaning a leaf node
```

2- recusive case

```
$0.forEachDepthFirst(visit: visit) // call the same method with it's children
```

Your method takes a closure  / completion that's be called for every node inside the main root node

So suppose You have root

```
0 
  - 1
     -  1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3

  -  2
     - 2.1 , 2.2 , 2.3
```

Here 0 node is called then when runnign your function

- visit(0)
- children.forEach {  // = 1,2

for 0 > 1

- visit(1)
- children.forEach {  // = 1.1,1.2,1.3

for 0 > 2

- visit(2)
- children.forEach {  // = 2.1,2.2,2.3

---

Inner case

for 0 > 1 > 1.1

- visit(1.1)
- children.forEach {  // end here as there is no childrens ( leaf node)

so on for 1.2,1,3

---

for 0 > 2 > 2.1 / 2.2 / 2.3 same as above case

---

**How to call**

your method is an instance method inside the tree so every node can call it , if you want to traverse nodes of 0 then do this

```
zeroNode.forEachDepthFirst {  (item) in
  print(item.name) // suppose node object has a name 
}
```

Then you will get

```
0 , 1 , 1.1 , 1.2 , 1.3 , 2.1 , 2.2 , 2.3
```

And that's as you called `visit(NodeObject)` for the main node and recursively all it's childrens

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we have `visit(self)` here?

Because if we didn't, we would never actually *do* anything to any of the nodes on the tree!

Consider this tree:

```
n1 -> n2 -> n3 -> n4
```

We now call our method `forEachDepthFirst` on `n1`. If we didn't have `visit(self)`, we would immediately call `forEachDepthFirst` on `n2`, which would call it on `n3`, which would call it on `n4`. And then we'd stop. But at no time would we have called `visit`, so we would have looped through every node in the tree without *doing* anything to those nodes.